# Compute the determinant of a matrix of solution for the following linear system.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

> Compute the determinant of a matrix of solution for the linear system $\left\{\begin{matrix}
> x_{1}'=x_{2}\\ 
> x_{2}'=tx_{2}
> \end{matrix}\right.$.

I can't figure out how to do this question. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Do I convert the system into matrix form?

Comment: The matrix of solution is known as the fundamental matrix or transition matrix. Once you compute it, determine its determinant. Notice, you can solve the second equation independently.

Comment: how do I solve this system? I am not sure what to do with the second equation.

Comment: $$
\int \frac{1}{x_2} dx_2 = t dt \implies x_2 = Ce^{t^2/2} , \quad x_2 > 0
$$